# onpage load check values for same data and display it in one string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a portal in vb.net where there are list of doctors etc. Now in my table of doctors I have made structure like (slot1MonringFrom, slot1MorningTo, slot1EveningFrom, slot1EveningTo) this 4 columns for only Monday now I have kind of different columns for all 7 days. Suppose on Mon, Wed, Thu doctors have filled same time then on page load it should check for same values & show it in one string like this (Mon, Wed, Fri - 8.00am - 12.00pm). Same way tue, thu have same time then it show in second string like (tue, thu - 4.00pm - 8.00pm).

I just want to know how do I check for same values & pass it in one string. If any example is given would be good to understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to implement logic as below,

```
Dim check1 as boolean = true
Dim check2 as boolean = true
Dim check3 as boolean = true
Dim check4 as boolean = true
Dim check5 as boolean = true
Dim check6 as boolean = true
Dim check7 as boolean = true


''''SLOT 1 CHECKING

check1=false
'compare slot1 variables with slot2, if matched, 
    'check2=false, contact slot1 and slot2

'compare slot1 variables with slot3, if matched, 
    'check3=false, contact slot1 and slot3

'do same for slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7

----------

''''SLOT 2 CHECKING

'if check2=true
    'if check3=false
        'compare slot2 variables with slot3, if matched,
            'check3=false, concate slot2 and slot3

    'do same for slot4, slot5, slot6, slot7

--------

''''SLOT 3 CHECKING
'if check3=true
.
.
.
.
. REPEAT SAME FOR ALL
```